# Does intramolecular hydrogen bonding occur in dicarboxylic acids?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, hydrogen-bond

Consider ethanedioic acid:

[image]

Could it form intramolecular hydrogen bonds (between the C=O and HO)?

[image]

Comment: It's theoretically possible, but I'm not sure if it's observed in practice

Comment: To add to @Mithoron 's comment, here is a [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S000926141000936X) to a paper where calculations suggest that intramolecular hydrogen bonding (like what you've drawn) occurs in oxalic acid.  Here is a [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=UzxAd1efKbcC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=oxalic+acid,+intramolecular+hydrogen+bond&source=bl&ots=I0FmnvHKjE&sig=6EvocQxGIjntef51i38OPqelCWY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XIkyVYmCE5e6ogT1roGYBA&ved=0CEgQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=oxalic%20acid%2C%20intramolecular%20hydrogen%20bond&f=false) to another reference that discusses this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this would not happen the way your second drawing depicts because the hydrogens do not orient themselves that way. Intramolecular hydrogen bonding would be no more feasible in ethandioic acid than any other monocarboxylic acid. See picture below:[image: oxalic acid]

Source: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Oxalic-acid-3D-balls-B.png

Comment: I'm afraid It's not a proof.

Comment: Why do you believe that the hydrogens "do not orient themselves that way"?  See my comment above, calculations suggest that a conformation with intramolecular hydrogen bonds is the most stable conformation.

Comment: It would be a large concentration of charge in a relatively small region of space. It is my understanding that the electron clouds and atoms orient themselves in a molecule so as to reduce this repulsion between the substituent atoms.